# How to add Principled volume as default

Tags: materials, smoke-simulation

Every time I add a material to a smoke domain, it always adds a "Principled BSDF" shader and not a "Principled Volume" shader. Is there something I should be doing to add the "Principled Volume" shader as default or should I just keep removing the "Principled BSDF" shader and adding a "Principled Volume" shader?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a default smoke material and save it in your default Blender starting scene if you find yourself doing smoke sims really often. Or you could write a small python script that create a domain with the right material and node setup. At the end of the day it's just a few extra clicks, I wouldn't bother with it. Principled BSDF is just the default setup for all Blender materials (remember that materials are completely independent data from objects).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I wondered if it was the default or if I was doing something wrong.